# Flaticon Icons from CDN stopped showing

Tags: html

They just stopped showing up randomly after a refresh. I got rid of all styling around the element and they are still not showing up. They also stopped showing up on a component I wasn't even working on. I checked on chrome and they were showing up, but then after a few refreshes (no changes, was just refreshing back and forth between browsers) they stopped appearing on chrome as well. I re-copied the CDN link from the website just to be sure and it still does not work.

I tried it on a starter file as well, not working on firefox or chrome:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdn-uicons.flaticon.com/uicons-regular-rounded/css/uicons-regular-rounded.css'>
</head>

<body>
    <i class='fi fi-rr-angle-left'></i>
</body>

</html>
```